# Downloading a pdf file by converting html using php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf

I'm trying to make an e-commerce website, where the user will click on the link and it will make an invoice and should download on client end a pdf file of the invoice which i've created in html, the thing is i used this code and it worked with ms word as .doc document but i want to do the same with pdf not working, code pasted below 
    
    `// the code to download invoice as word document, it's working 
    <?php
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename='.$result->tracking_number.'.doc');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>`

but same with this code is not working for pdf :(

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename='.$result->tracking_number.'.pdf');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

the pdf downloaded says the format is corrupted, what to do, i've to finish this asap :((

Comment: You should use a pdf lib like mpdf or TCPDF

Comment: i tried that too, but not working :(

Comment: What was not working? what have you tried? Can we see some code?

Comment: BTW since you use codeigniter see this page: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf

Comment: i followed everything in the above mentioned article but a pdf file is downloaded but when i open it say corrupted :(

Comment: `function pdf($tracking_number)
  {
   $this->load->helper(array('dompdf','file'));
   $data['result'] = $this->product_model->get_by_order_number($tracking_number);
   $html = $this->load->view('welcome/particular_order',$data,true);
   $data['again'] = $this->product_model->get_order_details($tracking_number);
   $html .= $this->load->view('welcome/order_details',$data,true);
   $data = pdf_create($html,'',false);
   write_file('name',$data);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }
}
?>

4) use it in your controllers like this

<?php
function pdf()
{
     $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
     // page info here, db calls, etc.     
     $html = $this->load->view('controller/viewfile', $data, true);
     pdf_create($html, 'filename');
     or
     $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
     write_file('name', $data);
     //if you want to write it to disk and/or send it as an attachment    
}
?>
```

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf